# What's the best way to implement a 2D interval search in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary, intervals, multimap

Suppose I have a 2D grid of intervals. A set of intervals along the x-axis and the same along the y-axis. Now I have to determine which intervals in x-axis and y-axis a new object belongs two. Let's say a new object has to numbers, one a x-coordinate and the other a y-coordinate. By determining the interval in x and y which the object fits into, I would like to retrieve some stored data.

I thought of something like a `std::map<IntervalX, IntervalY, DataToStore> map` or `std::multimap<IntervalX, IntervalY, DataToStore> map`. Any suggestions on how implement this, so that retrieving the stored data for the interval pair is quite efficient/fast and not in `O(n²)`.

**EDIT:**
An interval is determined by two float values. For example: An interval along the x-axis [0.5, 3.0). So 0.5 is contained and 3.0 would be not included in this interval but in the next interval in the positive x-direction.

The intervals are disjoint and not overlapping nor nested. The union of the intervals is some complete segment of the line. I did tile the plane in a set of rectangles and I want to know which rectangular region the point falls in.

For example: Intervals along x-axis staring at 0 to 10 with an interval size of 0.5 and along the y-axis starting at 2 to 15 with an interval size of 1.0. A given Point P(x=0.7,y=3.0) in which interval does it fall? It's the interval 2 on the x-axis and interval 2 on the y-axis. Now I need to retrieve the data stored for that interval pair.

In my use case, I will have around 10000 intervals along each axis and the determination of an interval for an object has to be fast, since I have to look up around 500 every 2 seconds (more or less).

Comment: What do you mean by 'interval' ? interval (space between) what and what ? a time interval ?

Comment: ordered storage of values in two dimensions sounds a bit like a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree)

Comment: How many "intervals" do you have? How many "objects"? What is your metric for "best"?

Comment: Voted to close as unclear. "interval" is undefined. "best" is undefined.

Comment: best is undefined? I thought my last sentence would make it clear enough. Added information definition.

Comment: Along each axis: are the intervals disjoint? overlapping? nested?  Is the union of the intervals some complete segment of the line? More information to characterize the intervals is needed.  Perhaps an example set of intervals showing all conditions between them that apply could be added to the question?  (E.g., did you tile the plane with a set of rectangles and you want to know which rectangular region the point falls in?  Or something else?)  (The question as it stands is unclear but can be improved with more details.)

Comment: Now that we know it is a tiled plane: A simple solution would be two sorted arrays - one for the X-axis intervals, one for the Y-axis intervals.  Then do two searches using `std::lower_bound`.  Expected complexity `log n` for each search.  It would be hard to do better and this code would be so simple and rely so much on the already tested `std::sort` and `std::lower_bound` you'd only need to look at it again if performance testing showed it to be a bottleneck.

Comment: And ... if you got those 500 in a batch every 2 seconds ... sort them too (twice: once on x and then on y) then search in sorted order using the lower bound of each item to reduce the number of items searched for the next item ... though really, now we're talking about an optimization that should only be tried after you determine you have a performance problem.

Comment: Good point so far. But "By determining the interval in x and y which the object fits into, I would like to retrieve some stored data." Where would that data be stored?

Comment: Elsewhere.  You'd have an index to the x-axis-interval-boundary array (vector) and an index to the y-axis-interval-boundary array (vector).  Party on.  (e.g., use x-index * 100000 + y-index as a map key, or use a 2D array of pointers indexed by x-index and y-index, or anything else you think of.)

Comment: Aw yeah ok, got it. So maybe I will stick with a 2D array of the type of my data.

Comment: Added my comments as an answer since you seem to approve of it, and so that it doesn't get lost in chat ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that we know it is a tiled plane: A simple solution would be two sorted arrays - one for the X-axis intervals, one for the Y-axis intervals. Then do two searches using `std::lower_bound`. Expected complexity `log n` for each search. It would be hard to do better and this code would be so simple and rely so much on the already tested `std::sort` and `std::lower_bound` you'd only need to look at it again if performance testing showed it to be a bottleneck.

And ... if you got those 500 in a batch every 2 seconds ... sort them too (twice: once on x and then on y) then search in sorted order using the lower bound of each item to reduce the number of items searched for the next item ... though really, now we're talking about an optimization that should only be tried after you determine you have a performance problem.

As to the data associated with each rectangular region of the plane:  Create a 2-D array of pointers to that data, indexed by the x- and y-indexes you got back from `std::lower_bound`.  Expected complexity of access into the 2-D array: constant.

Answer (score 0):

If the intervals don't overlap (sounds like it, since you state that a point maps to a single interval on each axis), I'd just store them in sorted order max(Interval_n) < min(Interval_n+1)  allowing an efficient binary-search lookup.

If they do overlap, you could sort on min, but this only helps you a little.